# Need to join three tables. Not sure which join fits the req

Tags: sql, oracle

table 1
AcctNO  CustomerId  Role    Name
1   123 A   ABC
2   121 B   BCA
3   321 C   CBA

table 2
AcctNo   CustomerId      Role            Address
1           123          A              1/12
2            121         B               11/3
4             231         C               12-1
3             321         C                111
5             221         C               121
table 3
AcctNo       CustomerId    Role           CompanyName
4              231         C                 hello
5              221          C                 bello
3              321          C                 cello

output should be as follows
AcctNo      CustomerId  Role             Name   Address      COmpanyName
1             123        A                ABC    1/12             NULL
2              121       B                BCA    11/3            NULL
3              321       C                CBA    111            cello
4              231       C                NULL   12-1            hello
5              221       C                NULL    121            bello

Comment: See [this great explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Well, there are only so many joins. Have you tried them? Have you tried *anything*?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? This really is a very typical JOIN problem so I'm not sure what exactly is the problem.

Comment: To get the `NULL` values you need to use outer joins.

Comment: You should normalize your tables. There's no reason to have `AcctNo`, `CustomerId`, and `Role` in all 3 tables.

Comment: I can see you have fake data in your example but I really hope that is a fake table structure too. You shouldn't have so much repetitive data. For example a CustomerID and Role should not be defined 3 times

Comment: actually i get these 3 tables from other dependant tables, so those new three tables will have a similar structure, yeah data is fake but not the structures

Answer (score 0):

Use a left join between the tables on a unique column like the **CustomerID**.
A left join is used instead of a inner join so you get any missing values as a null instead of missing a record.

Comment: If he uses an inner join he won't get `NULL` values as in his example.

Comment: Cheers, I missed the nulls